# MS Teams user calls out anonymous

Tags: microsoft-teams, softphone

One of our users keeps calling out externally with "anonymous" no matter what I try. Microsoft support unfortunately is not very helpful.  Anybody an idea what the possible problem could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

**Relevant setup info:**

- M365 E3 using MS Teams Calling plan (latest updates applied)
- Country: Belgium
- Hybrid setup (Private DC + Azure Sync)
- HP laptop + Softphone
- problem is present in the office and on remote locations
- no other users experience this problem

**Things tried so far:**

- Changed the phone number of the user
- Changed the license of user from national calling plan to international calling plan
- Re-applied policies with PS and Teams Admin GUI
- Changed "assigned policies" all to "global (org wide default)"
- Changed user to another client Laptop + manually updating client

Have a nice day everyone :) let me know should extra info be needed.

Comment: Just a wild guess.  Have you [cleaned out the teams cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-administration/clear-teams-cache)?  I have not seen this problem but I have solved MANY others because of data stored in the cache directory.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion :) Yes I have tried to clean out cache.  Forgot to mention that the issue persists when using another client laptop.

Answer (score 0):

in the end I had to recreate the whole user profile in O365 and migrate everything from the old to the new one.